# Reusable Ajax Call With Different Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing some software that makes ajax calls to a web API and returns some data. After completing the majority of work, I am going back through to see if i can refactor any code. From this I have realised that I make multiple ajax calls which have the same function asides from the parameters passed into them. With this in mind I wanted to refactor the ajax call into a reusable function or component of which I can then pass in different parameter fro each call, significantly reducing the amount of code. This is the ajax call I have created:

```
function AjaxCall (ajaxUrl, ajaxData){
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data: {
                ajaxData: ajaxData
            },
            dataType: 'JSON'
        });
    }
```

Later in my code I have then invoked this functioned as so...

```
var brandId = $('#brandDropdownList option:selected').prop('id');
var ProductUrl = "http://localhost:54442/api/products/GetProducts";

var getProducts =  AjaxCall(ProductUrl, brandId);

getProducts.done(function(data) {
            $('#productDropdownList').html('').append('<option id="-1" disabled selected="selected">Please Select a Product...</option>');
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                $('#productDropdownList').append('<option id="' + val.productId + '">' + val.productName + '</option>');
            })
        })
```

In this I get the id of a field from the UI and stored it in a variable called brandId. I then set the URL for the ajax call to use. I then invoke the function AjaxCall passing in productUrl and brandId. getProduct.done is then the success of which I append the data to a dropdown however this is relevant in the context of the question.

Basically my question is that where in the reusable component I have used ajaxData, I need the ajaxCall to use the passed in parameter brandId. So the actual ajax call I am wanting is

```
function AjaxCall (ajaxUrl, brandId){
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data: {
                brandId: brandId
            },
            dataType: 'JSON'
        });
```

This results in a request to the following URL "http://localhost:54442/api/products/GetProducts?brandId=1" which is what I want. But every time I want to make an ajax call the variable brandId will change for example to productId. So is there a way to have a reusable ajax call that I can pass in the different variables (brandId, ProductId to name a few) but also changing the variable in the data section of the ajax call to the passed in variable as otherwise the resulting URL is as follows: "http://localhost:54442/api/products/GetProducts?ajaxData=1".

Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks in advance

Comment: May I strongly recommend you use an interface that returns actual promises? Axios does that by default, but there are probably solutions you can download to keep using Jquery Ajax if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function, the `data:` property passed to `$.ajax()` should be `ajaxData`:

```
function ajaxCall (ajaxUrl, ajaxData){
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ajaxUrl,
        data: ajaxData,
        dataType: 'JSON'
    });
}
```

Then when you call it you can pass an object with any parameters you want:

```
let promise = ajaxCall(someUrl, { brandId: brandId });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just make the second parameter take an object as argument. This way you can pass any amount of parameters into the `$.ajax` call.

```
function AjaxCall (ajaxUrl, ajaxData){
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ajaxUrl,
        data: ajaxData,
        dataType: 'JSON'
    });
}
```

```
var ajaxData = {
    brandId: 5
};

AjaxCall('/products/GetProducts', ajaxData).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```